# How to prevent CSV injection when I upload CSV/Excel files

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, file-upload

My application has a feature of Uploading CSV/Excel files to Database server. SSIS in Database server in turn uses for data integration.

Issue is that application is vulnerable for CSV injection.

Example: If the malicious script is included in the excel template(any excel cell) during upload
such as

Malicious script:

> 1)=cmd|'/Ccmd'!'A1
>
> 2)=cmd|'/Ccalc'!'A1

Uploaded malicious file successfully. Navigated to that file and script got executed. This file was also saved at server for processing and same was executed at server also.

So i need to block the injection attack during the upload time itself.
If i need to read the file fully and check the same contain these characters (+, =, "", @) and validate on uploading itself. If it is to read line by line it will cause performance/time out issue especially with bulk files.

How can i prevent this injection in a best way without any performance hit.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you need to parse line by line, you can simply replace the characters in a single go, afterall CSV is a text file only.

Comment: You do not need to validate the files during upload. It is very common to handle that validation in batch. Add a state to each file which represents the current validation state and only allow access to validated files.

Comment: @Sir Rufo --  I do not want to allow to upload such a file of malicious script . I read somewhere we can include apostrophe before beginning of each cell so that it is considered as a text. But how do a developer can do in a simplest way. Any idea?

Comment: You can inspect the file only **after** uploading, so you have to allow it and then reject it after validation. But that validation process can be done in batch/background

Comment: @Sir Rufo  -- i do understand that ,but i really did not understand what is batch and how is it done..when u say batch is it through SSIS package?.. thank you

Comment: For python there is [defusedcsv](https://pypi.org/project/defusedcsv/). You could look into the implementation and watch out for performance aware implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can prevent CSV injection. Create a common  ExcelFilereader if you have Multipart request then firstly you convert Multipart to file content and read file and set condition in
ExcelReader that. If (cellReadContent.matches(pattern("+-#@="))
Then throw error else proceed to file upload